# Does an Obj important contain UV mapped textures?

Tags: texturing

I am almost a total beginner with blender. I purchased a model off of https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/maya-human-eye/818788. which came with a .obj file, a .mb files and some .jpg textures. On the website it says its already been fully textured and UVmapped. But when I import the .obj into blender, it does not appear to have any textures applied (and when I switch to rendered view it's just black).

I also tried loading the .mb file into maya and I see this green blob, though it does appear to contain textures and material properties. 
[image]

Given what you see, does the .obj file not have textures and is there no way to work with in blender?

Answer (score 1):

No, a .obj file does not contain textures. This is not a problem with Blender, but just an inherent thing to .objs. It stores the *mesh* information and actually includes UVs, but not the textures. You will have to import textures separately just like with any other application that uses .objs.